# how to run httpie from script.py

Tags: python, httpie

I need to send forms to a rest service from py-scripts. i try to do it using httpie.

when i invoke `run(['http', '--help'])` i've got expected result.
if i invoke `run(['http', 'http://site/page'])` the script is stuck and nothig happens.

I also tried to place running of httpie into bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
http http://site/page
```

the result is the same as in the first case. script is stuck.

I use ubuntu 16.04 so I have python2 and python3 at the same time. I run my script by python3. mayby is there a conflict between p2 & p3 in ths case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to include the `--ignore-stdin` option:

```
run(['http', '--ignore-stdin', 'http://site/page'])
```

> The `--ignore-stdin` option prevents HTTPie from reading data from
>   stdin, which is usually not desirable during non-interactive
>   invocations.
>
> — https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie#scripting